# Como mejorar esta funcion de split SQL Management 2018

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, function, sql-server-management

Encontre este codigo el cual me ayuda a mantener en memoria los datos que se ingresan en un parametro de mi informe, este funciona primero creando una tabla para registrar el nombre del usario y guardando los valores que el ingrese y otros campos adicionales

```
CREATE TABLE tblUserSetting(
      ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      UserID varchar(100) NULL,
      Report varchar(100) NULL,
      Setting varchar(100) NULL,
      Val varchar(max) NULL
   )
```

seguido creamos dos procedimientos almacenados los cuales permiten el primero setar los valores a la tabla y el otro obtenerlos

```
CREATE PROC spu_SetUserSetting
      (
         @UserID varchar(100),
         @Report varchar(100),
         @Setting varchar(100),
         @Value varchar(max)
      )
   AS
   BEGIN
      --Firstly delete any old settings for this parameter
      DELETE FROM tblUserSetting
            WHERE UserID=@UserID
            AND Report=@Report
            AND Setting=@Setting

     --Now add the new setting
      INSERT INTO tblUserSetting
         (UserID, Report, Setting, Val)
      VALUES
         (@UserID, @Report, @Setting, @Value)

     --Return the new setting
      SELECT @Value AS Val
  END

CREATE PROC spr_GetUserSetting
      (
         @UserID varchar(100),
         @Report varchar(100),
         @Setting varchar(100),
         @Default varchar(max)=NULL
      )
   AS
   BEGIN
      DECLARE @Val varchar(max)
      SET @Val = ISNULL((SELECT Val FROM tblUserSetting
            WHERE UserID=@UserID
            AND Report=@Report
            AND Setting=@Setting
         ),ISNULL(@Default,''))

     SELECT Val FROM dbo.Split(',', @Val) 
   END
```

Tambien esta esta funcion, pero no se como funciona o que es lo que hace ya que aun soy un principiante en el manejo de sql

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
      RETURNS table
   AS
      RETURN (
         WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
               SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s) 
            UNION ALL
               SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
               FROM Pieces
               WHERE stop > 0
      )
         SELECT pn,
            SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS Val
            FROM Pieces
   )
```

Y bueno, lo que me gustaria cambiar o mejorar es la manera de obtener los datos del procedimiento almacenado spr_GetUserSetting ya que al obtener los valores guardados de la tabla este me los trae de la siguiente manera(izquiera) y me gustaria que los trajera como este otro(derecha) la verdad no se que parte esta haciendo esto por eso pido su ayuda, gracias!

```
12132        12132,12353,52444
12353 
52444
```

Comment: Hola Leinad: Yo diría que antes de pedir nada, deberías de entender lo que hace, ya que las propuestas que te podemos dar, pueden generar más problemas que soluciones, sino sabes ni siquiera lo que hace, ni como lo hace. Dices en el título, `mejorar la función split de Sql Management Studio 18`. Management Studio es una herramienta para administrar bases de datos. Y la función `split`, es una función que tú has creado. Pero no tiene que ver con lo que solicitas luego. Porque pides cambiar la salida de `spr_GetUserSetting`.

Comment: Para entender lo que hace la función split, simplemente realiza llamadas con algún texto, que contenga separadores. `select * from dbo.split (',','a1,a2,a3') fn` y observa el resultado. Para entender lo que hace el procedimiento. Ejecútalo con parámetros. `exec spr_GetUserSetting 'aquí userid','aqui report', 'aqui setting', 'aqui default'`. O con los mismos parámetros y por partes. Ejecuta primero la select y luego la otra select y así sabes lo que hace. Por supuesto, que esto es mi opinión.

Comment: @Javifer2 gracias por tu ayuda, con lo que me comentaste para realizar llamadas a la funcion pude determinar que esa funcion hace que mis valores los acomode en columna como el ejemplo de la izquierda , pero me gustaria hacer que los valores los traiga como el de la derecha y esa funcion realmente no la hice yo, por eso me gustaria su ayuda para mejorar o acomodar esa funcion para traer los valores como mencione